# Connect namespace to internet using Second public ip address

Tags: ubuntu, namespace, network-namespaces

I have an Ubuntu18 server with Two public addresses

How can i create a namespace and connect to the internet through the second public ip?

(need to launch a program and force it to use the second ip to connect to the internet)

**ip a :**

```
    root@vm8950217476:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:40:ef:c5:bb:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 130.185.76.181/24 brd 130.185.76.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 130.185.76.18/24 brd 130.185.76.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9840:efff:fec5:bb62/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip route :**

```
root@vm8950217476:~# ip route
default via 130.185.76.254 dev eth0 proto static
130.185.76.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 130.185.76.181
```

I have reached some solutions stated here:

- [Connect network namespace to internet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287140/connect-network-namespace-to-internet)
- [One public IP address per Namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342607/one-public-ip-address-per-namespace)
- [Network namespaces and public IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338255/network-namespaces-and-public-ip)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214876/ubuntu-server-virtual-network-interface-with-internet-access

But after days of testing , still couldn't  make this work. The process looks confusing to me specially that I'm not sure which addresses I need to use in netns commands (ip addr , route , gw ,...)

**latest steps I tried:**

```
ip netns add test
ip netns exec test ip link set lo up
ip link add link eth0 name test0 type macvlan
ip link set test0 netns test
ip netns exec test ip addr add 130.185.76.18/24 brd + dev test0
ip netns exec test ip link set test0 up
ip netns exec test ip route add default via 130.185.76.254 dev test0

root@vm8950217476:~# ip netns exec test ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 130.185.76.18 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 130.185.76.18 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 130.185.76.18 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: Use a macvlan on eth0, remove 2nd IP from eth0, move macvlan into namespace, add 2nd IP to namespace. Default route is enough. If the whole process looks confusing, you need to read up on networking basics (google), so you understand **why** you do these steps. Following a recipe won't teach you that.

Comment: @dirkt well I'm searching on this for days and saw tutorials but almost all of them were working with local ip addresses not a secondary public ip address. Updated the post and added commands I tried. As you said, I removed the additional public address from eth0. and tried with macvlan but the network is unreachable inside namespace

Comment: Interesting. Try putting the **first** IP on the macvlan, and the **second** IP on eth0, and test both. This will tell you if it's an issue with the second IP address, or with the macvlan setup.

Comment: @dirkt switched the ips , still the same. The second ip looks fine since I can ping server or connect to ssh with that. so its probably something wrong with the setup

Comment: Just in case: After the `link set ... up`, do an `ip route` in the namespace and see if you have a default route via the macvlan. If not, add the one from the main namespace. Verify with `ip route get 8.8.8.8` inside the namespace to see if you have funny table entries somewhere for some reason. BTW, using a second ssh connection and starting a shell inside the namespace makes testing easier.

Comment: **ip netns exec test ip route** showed: 
`130.185.76.0/24 dev test0 proto kernel scope link src 130.185.76.18` .
I assume it doesn't have a default route? I added route using this command:
 `ip netns exec test ip route add default via 130.185.76.254 dev test0`. 
Now the ping starts but it doesnt have any data.
 **ip route get 8.8.8.8** shows: 
`8.8.8.8 via 130.185.76.254 dev test0 src 130.185.76.18 uid 0
    cache` . 
**traceroute 8.8.8.8** shows: 
` 1  * * *`.
The gw address I entered is base on the ip route of main interface (as mentioned in the post)

Comment: Maybe your VM setup filters on MAC address? Or it uses some special driver? It's difficult to debug that remotely, but at least your namespace setup seems to be correct now, and would work on real hardware.

Comment: @dirkt I didn't do a VM setup. Ordered this vps from a ISP.
Right now the ping inside namespace shows:
`From 130.185.76.18 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable`
Could be something wrong with the routing? **ip route** shows:
`default via 130.185.76.254 dev test0
130.185.76.0/24 dev test0 proto kernel scope link src 130.185.76.18`

Comment: "I didn't do a VM setup" But your ISP gave you a VPS, which is set up inside the environment of your ISP. For example, it could use the MAC address from the `eth0` "simulation" in the VPS to do something. And in that case, whatever is not working (and what could work) will depend on what your ISP does with the VPS.

Comment: When the ISP expects only one MAC address, ipvlan (in l2 mode) could be substituted here to macvlan without much or any other change.